# Cannot display images or play sound in my .exe if it is in a different folder

Tags: python, tkinter

When I convert my file in .exe and I want for example an image to be displayed or a sound to be played on my app I am forced to put them in the same folder otherwise the image will not appear and the sound will not play.

How can I display a image(png)/play a sound (a mp3) if my .exe and the used ressources (the image and the sound) are in a different folder ?
I've done for example `myimageframe = PhotoImage(file='myimage.png')` and `playsound('mysound.mp3')`

I would like to access the resources even on another machine if I transfer my .exe to a friend or myself on another computer

for the image(an error is raised):
[image: error]

the sound just doesn't play (nothing happen)

Comment: Seems like you are using `PyInstaller` to generate the executable.  You can use `--add-data` option of `PyInstaller` to include those image and sound files into the executable.  See official document on [Runtime Information](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html).

Answer (score 1):

`file='myimage.png'` is what's called a *relative* path - since there are no folders listed before, the app will look in the same folder where the .exe is *executed* from.

## From the same machine

- use absolute paths to the files (e.g. `C:\Temp\myImage.png`), or
- change the working directory to another location at runtime (e.g. `os.chdir("C:\Temp)`)

## From another machine

- find a way to embed the files' contents into the .py file (e.g. a base64-encoded string??),
- find a way to embed the files' contents into the .exe (no idea here - read the docs for your .exe bundler?)
- host the files on the public internet (e.g. a github repo, or file-supporting alternatives to PasteBin) & pull them down using `requests`

NOTE: that last option will require the running machine to have internet access, and should probably handle things gracefully if it doesn't....